# how to check the greater value in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, ipad

I am creating graph i get 5 values at run time so how should i know which is greater so that i may set max limit 
I have following 5 varibale of values;

```
    int value3=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemOneValue);
    int value4=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemTwoValue);

    int value5=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemThreeValue);

    int value6=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemFourValue);

    int value7=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemFiveValue);
```

how to check of the above varible which has larger value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *allValues = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemOneValue)], 
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemTwoValue)], 
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemThreeValue)], 
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemFourValue)],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemFiveValue)]];

int max = [[allValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
```

or

```
NSNumber * max = [allValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
```

An alternative that is less flexible but may be easier to understand:

```
int max = (value2 < value1) value2 : value1;
max = (value3 < max) value3 : max;
max = (value4 < max) value4 : max;
max = (value5 < max) value5 : max;
max = (value6 < max) value6 : max;
max = (value7 < max) value7 : max; 
// now max contains the highest of all values.
```

Comment: +1. very good, but IMHO it's too advanced for the question! :)

Comment: // max = (value3 > value4) ? value3: value4;
 // max = (value5 > value6) ? value5: value6;
        //max = (max > value7) ? max: value7;

Comment: i am using like this is it ok or not

Comment: but it is showing wrong answer i am posting code you can  see

Comment: @HermannKlecker i have posted code in your answer please look at that

Comment: Please do not update my answer. You may update your question. And no, your code example does not work. If either value3 or value4 is the maximum then this information would get lost in the very next line of your code. Why don't you go with my second alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a great article on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Here the pseudo-code to get min/max from an array:

```
 function select(list[1..n], k)
     for i from 1 to k
         minIndex = i
         minValue = list[i]
         for j from i+1 to n
             if list[j] < minValue
                 minIndex = j
                 minValue = list[j]
         swap list[i] and list[minIndex]
     return list[k]
```

---

- [Algorithm for max and min? (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710687/algorithm-for-max-and-min-objective-c)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima
- [How would you define a simple "min" method in obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125126/how-would-you-define-a-simple-min-method-in-obj-c)
- http://goo.gl/BO5Qx

---

In objc, the pseudo code became something like this:

```
  int value3=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemOneValue);
  int value4=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemTwoValue);
  int value5=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemThreeValue);
  int value6=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemFourValue);
  int value7=(int)roundf(appDelegate.itemFiveValue);

  NSArray *values = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:value3],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:value4],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:value5],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:value6],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:value7]];
  NSNumber min=0;
  NSNumber max=0;
  for ( int i=0; i<[values count]; i++ ) {
    min = [values objectAtIndex:i];
    //etc...
    for (int j=0; j<i+1; j++ ) {
      if ( [values[j] > min] ) {
        // etc..
      }
    }
  }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain this algorithm in simple logic using objective c

Comment: it is giving erro syntax where you have initialized array

Comment: it's an example. On stackoverflow i can't compile... :)